# Install SSL in AWS EC2

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that is using Amazon's custom linux install with built in apache. And Now I would like to Enable SSL to my instance what could I need to do for that.

Actually I bought URL from godaddy and placed my PHP files in AWS EC2. So where would I need to enable SSL, in AWS or in Godaddy? If in AWS means could you pls explain me how to enable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the apache ssl mod. not sure what OS you are running on ec2, but on Ubuntu it is 
    `a2enmod ssl`
then modify your ports file to make sure it listens on 443
    `/etc/apache2/ports.conf
    add the line:
    Listen 443`

and in your hosts file for the site you need to make sure the virtual host uses port 443 and include these lines
    `SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem // replace with the link to your cert.`

a complete version of a hosts file just for reference might be

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mysite.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,my instance running on Linux os